# Laravel whereIn from Model query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following code:

```
$my_companies = UserLocation::select('my_company_id')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();

$products = Product::select(array('id', 'code', 'name', 'um', 'VAT'))
        ->whereIn('my_company_id', array($my_companies))
        ->orderBy('name', 'ASC')
```

But I have zero records shown.

If I put constants  `->whereIn('my_company_id', [1,2])` is working, I can see the records.

Where is the error?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `lists` method to get an array of IDs:

```php
$companies = UserLocation::where('user_id', auth()->id())->lists('my_company_id');

$products = Product::select(['id', 'code', 'name', 'um', 'VAT'])
                   ->whereIn('my_company_id', $companies)
                   ->orderBy('name', 'ASC');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `pluck` method for Laravel 5.2.0 and above. According to Laravel documentation, method `lists` was renamed to `pluck`.
More info: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0

So the query is something like this:

```
$my_companies = UserLocation::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->pluck('my_company_id');

$products = Product::select(array('id', 'code', 'name', 'um', 'VAT'))
        ->whereIn('my_company_id', $my_companies)
        ->orderBy('name', 'ASC')
```